# Замена двузначных чисел на буквы

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь сделать замену двузначных чисел на соответствующую букву в массиве. Но работает криво. Код:

```
symbols = ["а", "А", "б", "Б", "в", "В", "г", "Г", "д", "Д", "е", "Е", "ё", "Ё", "ж", "Ж", "з", "З", "и", "И",
          "й", "Й", "к", "К", "л", "Л", "м", "М", "н", "Н", "о", "О", "п", "П", "р", "Р", "с", "С", "т", "Т",
          "у", "У", "ф", "Ф", "х", "Х", "ц", "Ц", "ч", "Ч", "ш", "Ш", "щ", "Щ", "ъ", "Ъ", "ы", "Ы", "ь", "Ь",
          "э", "Э", "ю", "Ю", "я", "Я", " ", "/", "[.-]", "`"];

function decode(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
    var t = "%" + i;
    var str = str.replace(RegExp( t, "g"), symbols[i]);
    alert(str);
  }
  return str;
}
alert(decode('%30'));
```

Например "%30", замена произойдет только первой цифры с процентом, т.е результат примет вид "Б0" (т.к 3-я буква в массиве "Б").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы еще смотрел на диапазон индексов массива

```
function decode(str) {
  var re = /%(\d+)/ig;
  var out ='';
  while ((res = re.exec(str)) != null)
         if(res[1] < symbols.length)  out += symbols[res[1]];
         else out += "?";
  return out;
}
console.log(decode('%3%30%343654%64')); // Бо?я
```

Comment: Спасибо, выбрал ваш вариант, работает)

Comment: Рад был помочь. Удачи!

Comment: Одна проблема. Если в закодированном тексте есть латинские буквы то он их удаляет.

Comment: Конечно, они совпадают с шаблоном. надо писать другой код

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется решение без циклов выглядит гораздо лучше: (регулярное выражение выглядит не очень конечно, но по-другому у меня не работало)

```
symbols = ["а", "А", "б", "Б", "в", "В", "г", "Г", "д", "Д", "е", "Е", "ё", "Ё", "ж", "Ж", "з", "З", "и", "И",
        "й", "Й", "к", "К", "л", "Л", "м", "М", "н", "Н", "о", "О", "п", "П", "р", "Р", "с", "С", "т", "Т",
        "у", "У", "ф", "Ф", "х", "Х", "ц", "Ц", "ч", "Ч", "ш", "Ш", "щ", "Щ", "ъ", "Ъ", "ы", "Ы", "ь", "Ь",
        "э", "Э", "ю", "Ю", "я", "Я", " ", "/", "[.-]", "`"];

        function decode(str) {              
            tmp = str.substr(1, str.length) 
            str = str.replace(new RegExp("\[0123456789][0123456789]","g"), symbols[parseInt(tmp)]);                 
            return str;
        }
        alert(decode('%30'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется ты какой-то ерундой занимаешься. Выглядит, как [XY-проблема](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Возможно [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) - это то что ты на самом деле имеешь в виду?

Т.е. может decode() должна выглядеть так (и поэтому, она вообще не нужна)?

```
function decode(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(str);
}
```

Comment: URIComponent сильно увеличит текст, а мне это принципиально важно.

Comment: Не понял, увеличит текст чего? Поправил ответ выше

Comment: Ну так если я декодирую текст, то должен и закодировать, если использовать encodeURIComponent то в закодированном виде длина текста в 6 раз больше. В моем же случае я написал функцию которая закодирует только 70 символов(русские буквы + 4 спец символа, этого достаточно ), так в закодированном виде текст будет больше максимум в 3 раза. Проблема у меня была только в декодировании.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю использовать обратный отсчёт `for (var i = 70; i > 0; i--)`:

```js
symbols = ["а", "А", "б", "Б", "в", "В", "г", "Г", "д", "Д", "е", "Е", "ё", "Ё", "ж", "Ж", "з", "З", "и", "И",
          "й", "Й", "к", "К", "л", "Л", "м", "М", "н", "Н", "о", "О", "п", "П", "р", "Р", "с", "С", "т", "Т",
          "у", "У", "ф", "Ф", "х", "Х", "ц", "Ц", "ч", "Ч", "ш", "Ш", "щ", "Щ", "ъ", "Ъ", "ы", "Ы", "ь", "Ь",
          "э", "Э", "ю", "Ю", "я", "Я", " ", "/", "[.-]", "`"];

function decode(str) {
  for (var i = 70; i > 0; i--) {
    var t = "%" + i;
    var str = str.replace(RegExp( t, "g"), symbols[i]);
  }
  return str;
}
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = decode('%3%30%34%64');
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```